# Display intro video first visit only Django

Tags: javascript, django, frontend

I have a Django app that needs to display a video that gives an into to the website. I only want it to do this on the initial visit as opposed to every time the user refreshes. I feel like sessions would have something to do with this but I’m not sure. Thanks!

Comment: If the user is logged in you could store "hasSeenIntroVideo" in the user's record in the server's database.  If the user is not logged in you could store it in the Session, which will last until that user goes away and next time he fires up your website in his browser he will see the video again (brand new Session).  If you only want the user to see the video once, ever (per user/browser combination), you could use a Cookie to store "hasSeenIntroVideo" in his browser, and then read that cookie next time he visits your site.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Can you provide an example on how one would do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its best to put this flag directly in your database. You can put a  field in your user model(if you are using custom user) or in a model which has `OneToOne`  relation with `User`. For example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    has_seen_intro = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And send this information to Template from view like this, for example:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       profile = self.request.user.profile
       if not profile.has_seen_intro:
           context['show_intro'] = True
           profile.has_seen_intro = False
           profile.save()
       # or  use user.has_seen_intro if you have custom model
       return context
```

And update the template like this

```
{% if show_intro %}
    // intro video codes
{% endif %}
```

#### Update

for anonymous user, please try like this:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            profile = self.request.user.profile
            if not profile.has_seen_intro:
               context['show_intro'] = True
               profile.has_seen_intro = False
               profile.save()
       else:
            if not self.request.session.get('has_seen_intro', True):
                 self.request.session['has_seen_intro'] = False
                 context['show_intro'] = True
       return context
```

Comment: This works for logged in users but all of my users are anonymous